# Apply function n-times; using output of last as input of next

Tags: r

I want to apply a function on an input to get an output. Then I want to use that output as an input for the next step and apply the same function that has been used in the previous step. I want to repeat so 100 times.
For example:

```
eq <- function (x) x^3 -2
eq0 <- eq(2)
eq1 <- eq(eq0)
.
.
.
eq100 <- eq(eq99)
```

Could anybody suggest a solution. Thank you!

Comment: `result <- numeric(101); result[1] <- eq(2); for (i in 2:101) result[i] <- eq(result[i-1])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a recursive way.

```
recur <- function(FUN = eq, x, n){
  if(n > 0) {
    x <- recur(FUN, FUN(x), n - 1)
  }
  x
}

recur(eq, 2, 100)
#[1] Inf
```

And a non-recursive one.

```
iter <- function(FUN = eq, x, n){
  for(i in seq_len(n)) x <- FUN(x)
  x
}

iter(eq, 2, 100)
#[1] Inf
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use something like a `while` loop

```
eq <- function (x) x + 1
i <- 1             #Index to count loop
n <- 2             #Starting value
while(i <= 10) {   #Check the condition, change this to 100 for your case
  eq1 <- eq(n)     #Call the function
  n <- eq1         #Store the new value into a variable to use it in next iteration
  i = i + 1        #Increase the counter
  print(n)         #Print the value
}


#[1] 3
#[1] 4
#[1] 5
#[1] 6
#[1] 7
#[1] 8
#[1] 9
#[1] 10
#[1] 11
#[1] 12
```

PS - I have changed the function to make it simple since the original function went to `Inf` immediately after few iterations.

Answer (score 2):

Just store the result in the same variable you are running the function on.

```
a=2
eq=function(x){
  x^3-1
}
for (i in 1:10){
a=eq(a)

print(a)
}
[1] 7
[1] 342
[1] 40001687
[1] 6.40081e+22
[1] 2.622435e+68
[1] 1.803492e+205
[1] Inf
[1] Inf
[1] Inf
[1] Inf
```